# Room changing ids on join query

Tags: android, sqlite, join, many-to-many, android-room

So we are using room library and it's easy to use but we have a problem it apperise like room is changing the ids of the objects when we use join queries.

```
@Query("select * from puzzles inner join list_puzzle_join on puzzles.id=list_puzzle_join.puzzleId where list_puzzle_join.puzzleListId=:puzzleListId")

List<Puzzle> getAllPuzzlesFromPuzzleList(String puzzleListId);
```

for example when we get puzzles Using the puzzlesDAO we get this ids :

```
6c6a5f74-d5bb-45c5-922b-b95bf608854c ,
03e34887-0d7d-4b6f-85d4-0a38ce3c0da9 ,
a9ac3435-cd35-4f7c-8bd3-e91b5514ecd2 ,
```

and when we use the join query we get :

```
2ba31014-f105-4f15-be01-f167b9afef55 ,
a23a48de-7552-4b27-a49c-369c3949f45c ,
4b9034a2-4936-4741-9448-6c57855cee6a ,
```

is it possible to get the correct its or is it like this by design??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is `select puzzles.*` but not `select *`. The query you are using now is likely to have 2 `id` field, which probably is the root cause.